# Problems With Effector In Fluid Simulation

Tags: modeling, animation, fluid-simulation

Today I am trying to create a fluid sim that pours coffee into a cup. I followed the general formula for creating and baking it but the liquid will not pour into the cup, it always fills up the domain instead of the effector. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? (only the useful objects)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it, here it is: https://blend-exchange.com/b/mrJlsne9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've applied the *Solidify* modifier of the cup, removed its scale keyframes, applied its scale, recalculated its normals, moved it a bit on +X (so that it falls on the good position) and recreated a keyframe so that it falls correctly, given it an effector *Surface Thickness* of 0.6, then recalculated the simulation (*Cache > Type > Replay*):

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I now know that applying the scale was probably the biggest factor